# How to create/start cluster from data bricks web activity by invoking databricks rest api

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have 2 requirements:

1:I have a clusterID. I need to start the cluster from a "Wb Activity" in ADF. The activity parameters look like this:

```
url:https://XXXX..azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/start
body: {"cluster_id":"0311-004310-cars577"}
Authentication: Azure Key Vault Client Certificate
```

Upon running this activity I am encountering with below error:

```
"errorCode": "2108",

"message": "Error calling the endpoint 
'https://xxxxx.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/start'. Response status code: ''. More 
 details:Exception message: 'Cannot find the requested object.\r\n'.\r\nNo response from the 
 endpoint. Possible causes: network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or 
timeout.",

"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "GetADBToken",
"GetADBToken" is my activity name.
```

The above security mechanism is working for other Databricks related activity such a running jar which is already installed on my databricks cluster.

2: I want to create a new cluster with the below settings:

```
url:https://XXXX..azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/create

    body:{

      "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
      "spark_version": "5.3.x-scala2.11",
      "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
      "spark_conf": {
      "spark.speculation": true
  },
    "num_workers": 2
}
```

Upon calling this api, if a cluster creation is successful I would like to capture the cluster id in the next activity.

So what would be the output of the above activity and how can I access them in an immediate ADF activity?

Answer (score 0):

For #2 ) Can you please check if you change the version 
  "spark_version": "5.3.x-scala2.11"
to 
"spark_version": "6.4.x-scala2.11"

if that helps